# Python: Efficient search in 3d numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, search, multidimensional-array

I have a 3d numpy array `(shape (z,y,x): 137,601,1200))` and face the challenge of finding the index of the value that is closest to 500 in every vertical column.
For instance I'd like to find the index that is closest to 500 for the array `(:,30,112)`. The numbers are ordered from bottom to top in descending order. For instance some of the 137 values of `(:,30,112)` could look as follows: `[1033.91 1031.35 ... 0.01]`.

My first approach is to apply a search function through every vertical column by means of a for loop. But I'm sure, there must be a faster way! Here is my first try:

```
from bisect import bisect_left

def takeClosest(myList, myNumber):

    pos = bisect_left(myList, myNumber)
    if pos == 0:
        return 0
    if pos == len(myList):
        return -1
    before = myList[pos - 1]
    after = myList[pos]
    if after - myNumber < myNumber - before:
       return pos
    else:
       return pos-1


def calcOptK(tnsr):
    # 2d array which saves the optimal levels
    optKs = np.zeros([601,1200])
    #iterate through the tensor and call on each point the search function    
    for y in range (0, 601):
        for x in range (0, 1200):
            optKs[y,x]=136-takeClosest(p3d[:,y,x][::-1],500)
    return optKs; 

optKs=calcOptK(p3d)
```

**UPDATE**: Thanks to @hpaulj and @Mstaino. 
This works perfectly:

```
optKs = np.argmin(np.abs(p3d-500), axis=0)
```

Comment: How about `np.argmin(np.abs(arr-500), axis=?)`?  That is get the distance from 500 for all points, and find the smallest along the relevant axis.

Comment: I sense from your code you are trying to find the closest but larger than value, not the absolute closest. If that is the case, please update the question.

Comment: @hpaulj's method should be significantly faster than your loop since it's vectorized. And since it's only 137 numbers I doubt using a binary search within Python will be faster than numpy's C loop.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj for the idea. But how and where exactly would I fit it into my code?

Comment: @Mstaino I try to find the absolute closest.

Comment: @Sev in that case hpaulj solution is by far the best, it doesn't even need your array to be sorted. To use it simply replace `arr` with your array and `axis=?` with the axis where you want to find your closest (if its in each of the 137 elements, use `axis=0`). If you cannot do it this way please update the question with what you have tried.

Comment: That's impressively shorter and faster than my solution. Thanks a lot!